# Откуда js берёт метод alert, если его нет в контексте функции?

Tags: javascript

Откуда js берёт метод, alert если его нет в контексте функции?

Выводится корктно

```
console.log(this.alert("1"));
```

если я выведу alert как метод обьекта я получаю ошибку

```
 const car = {
      carNumber: "A123",
      outputNumber: function () {
        console.log(this.alert("1"));
        console.log(this);
      },
    };
    
    car.outputNumber();
```

если я выведу просто alert без слова this у меня всё сработает

```
 const car = {
      carNumber: "A123",
      outputNumber: function () {
        alert(1);
        console.log(this);
      },
    };
```

Вопрос:

> Как работает функция **alert**, почему она срабатывает, если в моём понимание она находится в глобальном контексте, если нет глобального контекста откуда компилятор берёт эту функцию и запускает? Есть ли ещё скрытый контекст?

Comment: Прочитай, про прототипы в JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выполнении

```
console.log(this.alert("1"));
```

контекст `this` это `window`. У `window` есть функция `alert`

Когда выполняется

```
const car = {
  carNumber: "A123",
  outputNumber: function () {
    console.log(this.alert("1"));
    console.log(this);
  },
};
```

то `this` это объект `car`. А у объекта car нет функции или метода `alert`

Если объявить метод `alert` внутри объекта `car` и внутри вызвать `window.alert`, то заработает:

```
  const car = {
    carNumber: "A123",
    outputNumber: function () {
      console.log(this.alert("1"));
      console.log(this);
    },
    alert: function (txt) {
      window.alert(txt)
    }
  };
```

Можно так же использовать стрелочную фукнцию. У стрелочных фукнций нет контекста, они исполняются в глобальной области видимости

```
  const car = {
    carNumber: "A123",
    outputNumber: () => {
      console.log(this.alert("1"));
      console.log(this);
    },
  };
```

Когда вы вызываете фукнцию `alert` без привязки к контексту, то срабатывает глобальная функция `alert`(**window.alert**)

Comment: Тут ещё стоит упомянуть про строгий (strict) режим в котором без явного контекста `this === undefined`.